# How can i make sure \n does not register? when it is in a string

Tags: python

I want to get rid of `\n` from a string, so I am using `string.replace("\n", "")`
But when i do that it registers the "`\n"` as a new line,

I'm sure there is a simple solution but at the moment i am stuck. Future thanks.

SIDE NOTE: I can not use `strip()` because it appears a few times in the middle.

Here is the example:

```
stringExample = ["a", "\n", "b", "\n", "G"]
x = (str(stringExample))
y = x.replace("\n", "")
print(y)
```

`--> ["a", "\n", "b", "\n", "G"]`

Comment: You can use `.strip()` if it is at the end of the line

Comment: just use `rstrip()` but the code you posted should also work so I don't see the problem. `s ="foo\n bar"print(s.replace("\n", ""))` does not add a new line

Comment: 1.I can't use strip() as it is in the middle
2.It doesn't work there are no error message but it dosen't change anything

Comment: can you add an example of your input as I don't see any problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to concatenate the list into a string, you should not cast it to `str`, as this essentially just wraps it in quotes. You need to join it together like so:

```
x = ''.join(stringExample)
```

---

Example:

```
stringExample = ["a", "\n", "b", "\n", "G"]
x = ''.join(stringExample)
y = x.replace("\n", "")
print(y)
# abG
```

If you want it in a list like you had at the beginning, just cast `y` into a `list`.

Comment: Thanks, I am so grateful for your time =)